# HTACCESS and redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to make a redirect 301 via htaccess but for some reason it's doesn't works because I have more rules in htaccess, but if I remove them and leaves just the redirect it's works.

any idea?..

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 error.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml sitemap.php

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) seoPage.php?w=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: So we should guess what you have in your .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Put the redirect to the first place.

In htaccess the first matching rule workes.
So, there may be another rule overwriting this one.

Comment: I did: in the first line: Redirect 301 /test/ http://www.google.co.il/ and it's goes to: http://www.google.co.il/?word=/test/

Answer (score 0):

It does not seems to me you are doing 301 in whole document. 301 should look like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) seoPage.php?w=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

With emphasis on **R=301** . Check [this page](http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/redirect-www-and-no-www/). There in detail described what each part of rewriting rule mean. Alternatively you can check [documentation for .htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html).

Also lvil has a good point.

Comment: Yeah but I want to spasific page... and I want to ignore from this rule you wrote...